# Ступор с преобразованием типов в C++ / Qt. std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >

Tags: c++, qt, строки, cast

Приветстсвую! Решил поработать с двоичными числами в Qt, а точнее разобраться с константами из enum'a QStyle :: StateFlag.

Что я хочу?
Вывести константу в виде двоичного числа, преобразованного в виде std::string.

Что я делаю?

```
std::bitset<32> temp(static_cast<int>(QStyle::State_AutoRaise));
qDebug() << temp.to_string();
```

В чём проблема?
Получаю ошибку:

```
invalid operands to binary expression ('QDebug' and 'std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >')
```

Но проблема в том, что никакой static_cast не помогает в этом случае... Подскажите как справиться с моей задачей в C++ / Qt. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: а причем тут static_cast ?  Я не интересуюсь QT, но прочитав сообщение об ошибке, не трудно понять, что  оператор << не может иметь правым операндом std::string, когда слева  qDebug()

Comment: `qDebug() << temp.to_string().c_str();` или `qDebug() << QString(temp.to_string().c_str());`. В общем, скормите ему `QString`

Comment: Совет, не используйте ничего из стандартной библиотеке при работе с кутэ. Используйте только тогда, когда это на самом деле необходимо.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо vt-egorov, за ответ, это помогло!
Также нашёл вот такое решение:

```
qDebug() << QString::number(QStyle::State_AutoRaise, 2);
```